# Use exactly 36 combinations instead of two dice

Tags: catan, probability, dice

I like playing Settlers of Catan with one extension: "Catan: Event Cards"

The deck consists of 36 dice cards to represent the 36 different combinations that can be rolled with 2 dice. This means that number "rolls" are evenly distributed according to its probability.

How can I get this running on Android? Is there a way to roll two dice with predictable probability?

There is one [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kosmos.catan.assistent), where you can use those cards, but unfortunately there is one card in it that causes shuffling of all cards, which destroys the probability sorting.

- http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/20038/catan-event-cards?
- http://www.catan.de/spiel/ereignisse-auf-catan

Especially in settlers I would also like to take the sevens out of the pile and roll each turn only to have random amounts of sevens but if I didn't roll a seven I would take one card instead.

Also optimal, I would like to have such a dice app that allows to set the number of dice to one or more and roll accordingly to play other games too.

How can I get this running on Android?

Comment: It seems like you are wanting to 'stack the deck'. Isn't that deck supposed to be shuffled between every turn? If not, it is not holding the same probablity as 2D6, despite having 36 options. If you think about it, once a card is drawn, even if it is placed on the bottom of the deck, it is 100% certain that it will NOT be drawn the next turn. Therefore, the next player is playing with 35 cards. The following player 34 cards, and so forth. Thus, to reflect 2D6, the cards should be shuffled between turns. Unless, you like how those numbers are.

Comment: It is not about playing those cards. What I try to achieve is about creating an alternative for games that rely on much luck into a more strategical way: If all numbers are now "drawn" as many times as the propability of the dice predicts, you can for example at settlers rely on the resources you expect to gain if you set your town at an eight.

Comment: If you're going to use something like this, I would recommend never using the entire stack, because it gets predictable towards the end. You could use half a stack, or you could add a 'shuffle now' card to the deck.

Comment: Shuffle now cards make it totally random again. I think it is not a great drawback that it is predictable towards the end. It allows more strategy for everyone

Comment: Without getting into how much I disagree with your motivations here (besides mentioning it), a good solution would be the [Clay Crucible variant](http://claycrucible.com/2014/07/clay-crucible-settlers/). After initial setup, there is no randomness.

Comment: It would not be 'totally' random. It would result in a better spread of each of the outcomes of the dice, since you're forcing 18 outcomes in a row to be distinct outcomes of a 2x6 dice roll. You can't get more than twice the normalized outcome with half a card stack, while with dice you can theoretically play a game where no 8 is rolled at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an app called [Catan Smart Dice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.s1m0n.catanstat) which does exacly what I need.

With the possibility to have the dice be a **fair dice**: there are 36 possible rolls (1-1, 1-2, 1-3...) And such a fair dice rolls all the possible permutations once before repeating a permutation again

---

Also an app, where you can also adjust the number of dice and adjust the "fairness": [Fair Dice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaybogerd.fairdice)

Comment: If it's guaranteed to roll all 36 before it repeats one, it isn't a fair dice roll.

Comment: An example of what corsiKa is talking about: If you count the rolls and how many are sevens, you get an extraordinary amount of information about the robber. "Oh, it's the seventh seven? I'll use my soldier now, knowing that you have to get a dev card or suffer the soldier for at least 10 turns!"

Comment: What are you talking about? And there are only 6 sevens in 36 rounds.

Comment: @rubo77 He meant the sixth seven; but the point still stands. This is why the official event cards have a card that causes them to reshuffle.

Comment: the original event cards try to simulate two dice. But I want to change the game into a more strategical, so I am fine with knowing exactly which numbers are still to come within 36 rounds. every player knows this, so it is totally fair